# Android - Picking both time and date

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to build an application in which there is a Date & Time which is being displayed in an `EditText`. When the user clicks on the `EditText` it should open the `DatePicker`, if the user has selected the date or clicked on an ok `Button` it should then automatically open the `TimePicker`.

I want both values to be handled and displayed in the same `EditText`. I have written the methods: `getDatePicker` and `getTimePicker` and they both work.

How would I combine them? Would I be able to open the `getDatePicker` in a `Dialog` and have an OK button, when the button is clicked it stores the value in a `String` and opens the `getTimePicker` in the same `Dialog`?

Here is the code for the `getDatePicker`, the `getTimePicker` looks exactly the same apart from using the `TimePicker`:

```
private static void getDatePicker(Context context, final TextView dateValue)
{
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            // Month formatting and handling the month index starting at 0 instead of 1
            String monthValue = ((monthOfYear + 1) > 0 && (monthOfYear + 1) < 10) ? ("0" + (monthOfYear + 1)) : String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1);
            // Day formatting
            String dayValue = (dayOfMonth > 0 && dayOfMonth < 10) ? ("0" + dayOfMonth) : String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
            String dateToPrint = year + "-" + monthValue + "-" + dayValue;
            dateValue.setText(dateToPrint);
        }
    }, year, month, day);
    datePicker.show();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You can also create custom control to get date and time picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dateValue.appendText()` is all you need.

Comment: Hi @Neil, thank you for your answer. I will try that. Just to confirm, instead of doing `dateValue.setText();` I should use `dateValue.appendText();` instead?

Comment: It just saves you an extra string variable, no magic in this method